# Can I make my Delphi App start at a specific time (like 12:00AM), without the application running?

Tags: delphi, startup, delphi-xe2

I saw an installed application, that feeds some XML data from the vendor's website and displays it in the Main Form window. Simple stuff, I suppose, but whgat I noticed was that, even when I close the Application in the system tray, tomorrow morning (at exactly 12:00AM) it pops ups again! This is so cool. I am not sure that it was written in Delphi, probably some .NET IDE or somehting.

Can Delphi XE2 achieve this? If so, how can I get that to work?

Comment: What do you mean by not running? If there is a notification icon in what you call the tray then an app is running to support that icon.

Answer (score 8):

Windows can achieve this: Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add / manage Task Scheduler in your delphi application, there is a JCL library specially created for that :

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JclTask.pas

There is no documentation but you can see the source code and use the TJclTaskSchedule to add executing your own application in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically create a scheduled Task either use the "schtasks.exe" command line utility that comes with Windows or an interface to the Task Scheduler API. An alternative to the JCL library is the commercial "[VCL Scheduling Agent](http://www.sicomponents.com/taskscheduler.html)" component for Delphi.